# Reading password protected XLSX on linux (and windows) with Perl

Tags: linux, perl, excel

I'm trying write a simple perl script that reads some fields from a password protected XSLX file.

I've looked at [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~dmow/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.13-withoutworldwriteables/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm) and [SimpleXlsx](http://search.cpan.org/~jestock/SimpleXlsx-0.0.3/lib/SimpleXlsx.pm) but neither seem to support password protected files.

Any idea how this can be done?

Using Win32::OLE
This is done like so:

```
my $Book =
  $Excel->Workbooks->Open( { FileName => $file, Password => $password } );
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, sadly not straight forward then. Luckily I have the option of reading an old style xsl and this is simple using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.

Comment: Given that my suggestion was basically a kludge to convert the XLSX back into an XLS so you could read it, I heartily agree that if you can get the file still provided as old XLS that's a better way to go.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the current Perl xlsx reading modules support reading encrypted files.

It isn't straightforward to decrypt these files since the encrypted XML files are stored in an OLE container document as opposed to the usual ZIP container.

Answer (score 1):

This "should" be doable with OpenOffice/LibreOffice. There seem to be quite a few bugs around xlsx and encrypted file support, not to mention the combination, so I'd try opening the files in LibreOffice GUI first and if that works for your specific files, call it via library or command line.

[OpenOffice::OODOC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/OpenOffice-OODoc/) is the Perl connector, if that doesn't work you can use the command line to convert to a non-password protected file and then open it in your tool of choice.