# Remove password from Excel spreadsheet - Password Known

Tags: php, perl, excel, passwords

We have a bunch of Excel spreadsheets that are processed by a Perl script.  These spreadsheets are password protected (we know the password).  What we need is to be able to remove the password from the spreadsheet using either Perl or PHP and save the decrypted file.  The script will be running on a BSD server.

Comment: Unfortunately the files are .xls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it is not possible on linux: [Reading password protected XLSX on linux (and windows) with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967224/reading-password-protected-xlsx-on-linux-and-windows-with-perl)

(You may could open/convert it using OpenOffice/Libreoffice but that not an easy way)

If you run it on windows you might be able to do it with win32::ole http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=319647

A bit mmore detailed code example: http://bytes.com/topic/perl/answers/746842-opening-password-protected-excel-file-using-win32-ole-perl